# Kotlin type mismatch !! and?

Tags: types, kotlin, mismatch

I just recently started studying kotlin and when I changed  Webrtc release  to a newer one(1.0.22920) encountered  following problem:

```
 Type mismatch: inferred type is PeerConnection? but PeerConnection was expected
```

Here is the part of code where the error occurs:

```
val rtcConfig = PeerConnection.RTCConfiguration(iceServers)
peerConnection = peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig, getPeerConnectionMediaConstraints(), videoPeerConnectionListener)
```

Most likely this is due to the fact that in the Webrtc library createPeerConnection became @Nullable:

```
@Nullable
      public PeerConnection createPeerConnection(RTCConfiguration rtcConfig, MediaConstraints constraints, Observer observer) {
        long nativeObserver = PeerConnection.createNativePeerConnectionObserver(observer);
        if (nativeObserver == 0L) {
            return null;
        } else {
            long nativePeerConnection = nativeCreatePeerConnection(this.nativeFactory, rtcConfig, constraints, nativeObserver);
            return nativePeerConnection == 0L ? null : new PeerConnection(nativePeerConnection);
        }
    }
```

Attempt to put ? and !! in different places did not work.

I think that only my poor knowledge of kotlin separates me from solving the problem, can you help me?

Comment: Can you show where you specify `peerConnection`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most probably because earlier you have declare the variable as not nullable:

```
var peerConnection: PeerConnection
```

And that means you cannot assign a `@Nullable`value to that variable.
Change that to:

```
var peerConnection: PeerConnection?
```

Or you can force the value being returned to be non-null, (which I do not recommend) in which case:

```
peerConnection = peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(rtcConfig, getPeerConnectionMediaConstraints(), videoPeerConnectionListener)!!
```

Notice the `!!` at the end.

Answer (score 2):

Since the method is nullable, this means it has a chance of returning null. This means you cannot declare it as a non-null `PeerConnection`. You have three choices here:

1. Declare the var as `PeerConnection?` - this means you accept nullable values
2. Use non-null assertion with `!!`. At the end of the call to `createPeerConnection`, add `!!`. This throws an exception if it's null.
3. Use the Elvis operator - add `?: [something to do here if it returns null without brackets]` after the call to `createPeerConnection`.

If you need PeerConnection to be non-null, I recommend you pick the last option. It's also a recommended option if you're checking for null, as:

```
var someNullableVar = getPossibleNull()
if(someNullableVar == null) someNullableVar = whatever();
```

is the same as:

```
var nonNullVar = getPossibleNull() ?: whatever()
```

You can also return and stop continued execution, but if you want to throw an exception, use `!!` instead of the Elvis operator.

If you pick option #1 though, note that this means you'll have to do null checks on calls later.